# Installing Irrlicht on MaxOS Lion

Tags: osx-lion, irrlicht

I'm having trouble building Irrlicht Engine on MacOSX Lion. The process described on [the wiki](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.InstallingIrrlicht) is not updated for Lion, and byt following [this discussion](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44579) I found on the web, I tried to build using `xcodebuild -sdk macosx10.7 -arch x86_64`, but I get the following error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/MacOSX.build/Release/libIrrlicht.a.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/COpenGLSLMaterialRenderer.o ../COpenGLSLMaterialRenderer.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
(1 failure)
```

My knowledge of MacOS building procedures and xcode terminal commands is limited, anyone could light me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up finding the answer myself: http://dbrgames.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/compiling-irrlicht-1-7-2-with-mac-os-10-7-and-xcode-4-1/

Worked for me like a charm.